# pihole - Can I call a local top level domain name anything?

Tags: networking, dns, lan, local, pihole

Possibly a stupid question, but I am setting up pihole on my home network. I am sure it has been asked before but searching didn't yield any relevant results, Maybe just the way I asked.

I added some .local address mappings and they work fine.

Then I felt experimental and added a `media.moon` mapping to a local LAN address, but entering that sent me to google showing me moon pics.

Does that mean it can't work? Or are there configs I have to tweak or something?

Comment: It all depends on how you have your DNS setup. If you have your pihole as first DNS server, it should catch media.moon and direct it to your pihole. Keep in mind that the hostname could be cached in your browser though, so clear that too. Do note that you could even do something like microsoft.com, but then you would not be able to visit the real site anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes, as long as your DNS server answers to a name, then that name "exists" from your computer's point of view. (And of course, as long as your computers query *your* DNS server.)

In practice though, some web browsers (Chrome in particular) like to be picky about it, and will internally compare the domain name against their own internal "List Of TLDs That Currently Exist On Internet". If the name uses a TLD that's not on the list, Chrome will assume it's a search term – *unless* you type `http://` as well, in which case it'll reluctantly accept it as a DNS domain.

(Above the search results page in Chrome, you might have a "Did you want to visit http:/‍/media.moon?" bar showing up.)

It might help to decide on a single domain (e.g. `.moon`) and *distribute it via DHCP* so that the OS automatically suffixes the domain without you needing to do so; if I remember correctly, Chrome pays attention to the "Domain suffix" information received from DHCP.

As far as the choice of domain goes, `.local` in particular is *not* recommended; it is in practice meant exclusively for mDNS-based (i.e. serverless) hostname lookup and service discovery, and using it with regular DNS will interfere with that.

---

Inventing custom domains also doesn't 100% work if you have DNSSEC validation enabled – doing DNSSEC validation with the ICANN root keys has the implicit assumption that the ICANN view of DNS is the 'true' view, so if the computer gets an answer for "media.moon" but *also* finds a DNSSEC-signed record saying that .moon doesn't exist (or that this particular subdomain doesn't exist), that's going to result in a failed query.